# Crash when closing a refreshing thread

Tags: android

I made a music player that crashes every time I try to close it if I enable refreshing the thread every sec (refreshing is for updating the elapsed time of the song and the progressbar). Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Background Runnable thread
 * */
private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
       public void run() {
           long totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
           long currentDuration = mp.getCurrentPosition();

           // Displaying Total Duration time
           songTotalDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
           // Displaying time completed playing
           songCurrentDurationLabel.setText(""+utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));

           // Updating progress bar
           int progress = (int)(utils.getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration));
           //Log.d("Progress", ""+progress);
           songProgressBar.setProgress(progress);

           // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
           mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100); //this line is causing errors
       }
    };
```

This all again works while in the activity, but as soon as I press the back button it crashes. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Show logcat so we know what you mean by 'crashes'.

Comment: How to paste logcat in a readable format?

Comment: By adding a code tag to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try stopping the future callbacks with [`removeCallbacks()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks%28java.lang.Runnable%29) in `onPause()` or a similar method:

```
mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
```

---

> if I enable refreshing the thread every sec

You seem to want to run your code once a second, but you use...

```
// Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100); //this line is causing errors
```

Understand that Handlers and Runnables are not created in a new Thread by default and that a 100 millisecond delay executes your code 10 times a second.

Comment: oops, i meant every 1/10th of a sec.. I'll try your suggestion now! :)

Comment: Silly me for doing that in the activity, but not on exit... Anyway, I added `mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);` in onDestroy and it works perfectly, thanks!